Power BI Top N filter being ignored
I'm about to lose my mind on why this isn't working. I'm merely trying to implement a Top N filter and the visual is just completely ignoring it. What else can I check to explain this? I have an original report from which I'm modifying and the original is working as intended, despite that I've duplicated it exactly from what I can see. So I am clearly missing something, I just don't know what it is.

And to be clear, this is the original with virtually the same data output:


UPDATE 1: I started changing the N value to see what may have changed and oddly enough, it's the # counts that change.



SOLUTION: I wanted to provide a more specific description of what resolved my problem, in hopes it helps others. What I had done originally was simply add another filter on # (right-clicked on # in Data pane on right, selected Add To Filters). This did not work and contributed to the odd behavior I documented regarding changing the N value in my first Top N filter. So what resolved this was by changing my pre-existing Region filter (in first screenshot, it is seen below highlighted filter as "Region is (All) ). By changing this to a Top N, my filter worked as expected. It seems the trick is that the filters must be specific to how the data must be "grouped", for lack of a better word.

Try setting the TopN on Region and not #.


Unfortunately, that had no effect on the number of columns returning.

Can you share a snip with the TOPN applied to the Region please?

Ok, so what I had done was change my existing Top N filter to reference Region instead of #, as seen in the screenshot. But then I cleared that filter and changed my existing Region filter you're pointing at to use a Top N and it is working as intended now. There's clearly an aspect to these filters I'm not yet understanding, but I think this interaction may help. Thank you!

No worries, glad it sorted it out. Read out load what you need to, "show me TOPN Regions based on the value of #". Where what you had was "show me TOPN of # based on #".
